# Getting costs from multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing, aws-cost-explorer

I have been using the Boto3 CostExplorer SDK to query my costs within my account. I am recently been put in charge of managing multiple costs and would just like to run a script weekly to query the costs across all the accounts, but when looking into get_cost_and_usage (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce/client/get_cost_and_usage.html) it seems I can only query the account that I am in. I am wondering if is there an alternative way. I was hoping to grant permission to lambda to query across accounts via a cross-account IAM role.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/?